# Heights of the inner parallelogram

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

From the quadrilateral below, it says '`ρ1` and `ρ2`, are the heights of the inner parallelogram.

[image]

What is the description/definition of height in this case? Thanks...

Comment: height $\cong$ length

Answer (score 1):

Apparently by a "height" they mean "perpendicular distance from a vertex to a side". Others call this an "altitude" (not "attitude"). But I don't think it is standard convention.

Comment: ρ1 & ρ2 will be the same when using different vertix, right?

Comment: @JRGalia: Well in this case you only get two possible "heights".

Answer (score 0):

The hieght of a parallelogram $ABCD$ wrt. a side $AB$ is the value $x$ such that 
$$ S_{ABCD} = x \cdot AB$$

Comment: can you provide more detail or link for the details? thanks...

Comment: @JR Galia Err... Isn't that a common definition? It is just the distance from $C$ or $D$ to $AB$.

Comment: thanks... that's clear enough... but it seems not reflected on the drawing...

Comment: Why so? $\rho_1$ is just the distance from a midpoint to the segment (side) formed by two other midpoints. Same for $\rho_2$.